Ocultar contenedor en flet
Estoy aprendiendo flet python, tengo un problema al querer ocultar un contenedor, estoy usando este código:
page.controls.remove.pop(contenedor_programador)

pero me da error, por favor me ayudan como puedo ocultar y mostrar un contenedor de flet. Gracias de antemano.

Hola Yamil, considera agregar un [mcve] y sobre todo la traza completa del error, "me da error" no aporta ninguna información. Debes explicar que widgets quieres eliminar, estás mezclando (intentando encadenar o no se muy bien que) dos métodos distintos que permiten eliminar un widget page.controls.pop() y page.controls.remove(control_a_eliminar), el primero elimina el último de la lista, el segundo recibe como parámetro una referencia  al que debe eliminar....

Te da error porque no le pusiste el “ al final y al inicio
page.controls.remove(“control_a_eliminar”)


No, contenedor_programador no debería llevar las comillas. El problema es que está llamando a pop pasándole una referencia (ccontenedor_programador) y no debería. Además de que está llamando a pop a través de remove lo que no tiene sentido tampoco.

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
